# Flask-jwt installed but it's showing Not Found / Not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jwt, flask-jwt

I have installed flask-jwt in VS Code using "pip install Flask-JWT" but in my code, it's showing Not Installed. How to solve the issue?

[Click here to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tu84.png)

Comment: Please add the actual formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I see that you are using **virtualenv**, have you configured **VS Code** to run the application through the version of python installed with virtualenv?
If not, take a look at this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Probably you need to configure the right interpreter in the **setting.json** file by adding:

```
python.pythonPath: "Scripts\\python.exe"
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I did not choose the python interpreter of virtualenv. Now it's working after selecting the right interpreter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
pip install PyJWT
```

and import like this

```
import jwt
```

Comment: I also tried this but failed. The actual issue was that I did not select the python interpreter which was installed with venv.